# Why express-session (SameSite atribute) isn't working on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies, express-session

I am developing a web app with Express.js and React.js.
I am using express-session but it is not working.
This is how i am using it:

```js
app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    ttl: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
  }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true, 
    secure: false,
    SameSite: 'strict',
  }
}));
```

I tried with "secure" in true, false, auto and all possibles combinations. And always had the same Chrome issue:

> In a future version of the browser, cookies marked with SameSite=None must also be marked with Secure to allow setting them in a cross-site context. This behavior protects user data from being sent over an insecure connection.
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
> Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a note that "In a future version of the browser" is right now. This feature has been turned on for a small percentage of users in the last few days. https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

Comment: Yes, i just read it.
But i still does not understand why it works in my Mac's Chrome, works on my Windows Chrome, but in my partner's Chrome no. And i dont know how to solve it...

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: same problem here too, doesn't seem like anyone has really released much helpful info on this subject yet

Answer (score 8):

There is an example with session, and mongoStore:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = session({
  secret: 'SuperSecret - (Change it)', //!settear una variable de entorno. 
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60
  })
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`SameSite: 'strict'` is the issue! The first 'S' should be lowercase in JavaScript `sameSite: 'strict'`.

Also, if that doesn't solve your problem, could it be possible that it's not actually a same site request and you need to revise it to `sameSite: none`. I could be wrong, I don't know anything other than what you shared, but just wanted to throw that out just in case!